# Centering the object into the 3D space with Direct3D

Tags: c++, winapi, direct3d

The idea is to present a drawn 3D object "centered" in the screen. After loading the object with [WaveFrontReader](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMesh/blob/master/Utilities/WaveFrontReader.h) I got an array of vertices:

```
    float bmin[3], bmax[3];
    bmin[0] = bmin[1] = bmin[2] = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    bmax[0] = bmax[1] = bmax[2] = -std::numeric_limits<float>::max();

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        for (auto& v : objx->wfr.vertices)
        {
            if (k == 0)
            {
                bmin[k] = std::min(v.position.x, bmin[k]);
                bmax[k] = std::max(v.position.x, bmax[k]);
            }
            if (k == 1)
            {
                bmin[k] = std::min(v.position.y, bmin[k]);
                bmax[k] = std::max(v.position.y, bmax[k]);
            }
            if (k == 2)
            {
                bmin[k] = std::min(v.position.z, bmin[k]);
                bmax[k] = std::max(v.position.z, bmax[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I got the idea from the Viewer in [TinyObjLoader](https://github.com/tinyobjloader/tinyobjloader/blob/master/examples/viewer/viewer.cc) (which uses OpenGL though), and then:

```
    float maxExtent = 0.5f * (bmax[0] - bmin[0]);
    if (maxExtent < 0.5f * (bmax[1] - bmin[1])) {
        maxExtent = 0.5f * (bmax[1] - bmin[1]);
    }
    if (maxExtent < 0.5f * (bmax[2] - bmin[2])) {
        maxExtent = 0.5f * (bmax[2] - bmin[2]);
    }
    _3dp.scale[0] = maxExtent;
    _3dp.scale[1] = maxExtent;
    _3dp.scale[2] = maxExtent;

    _3dp.translation[0] = -0.5 * (bmax[0] + bmin[0]);
    _3dp.translation[1] = -0.5 * (bmax[1] + bmin[1]);
    _3dp.translation[2] = -0.5 * (bmax[2] + bmin[2]);
```

However this doesn't work. With an object like [this spider](https://free3d.com/3d-model/spider-animated-low-poly-and-game-ready-87147.html) which has vertices that the coordinates do not extend +/-100, the scale gets to about 100x by the above formula and yet, with the current view set to 0,0,0 the object is too close and I have to put the Z translation manually to something like 50000 to view it into a full box with a `D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport = { 0.0f, 0.0f, w, h, 0.0f, 1.0f };`, Not to mention that the Y is not centered as well.

Is there a proper algorithm to center the object into view?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can actually change the position of the camera itself and not the objects.

Its recommended that you edit the camera position in OpenGL tutorials.

In games the camera (which is what captures the viewpoint which the rendered objects are viewed from) are not in the middle of the view but actually further way so you can see everything going on in the view/scene.